# Emacs: how to create yasnippets for different RDBMs in sql-interactive-mode

Tags: emacs, yasnippet, sql-interactive-mode

I am using sql-interactive-mode to connect to 2 databases: MySQL and SQLite. I created yasnippets for mysql in `yasnippets/sql-interactive-mode` folder. For example to add a column in MySQL I use the following snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: Add column
# key: addcol
# --
ALTER TABLE $1 ADD COLUMN \`$2\` $3;
```

But SQLite uses different syntax. How can I create different yasnippets for different databases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained [here](https://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-2) you can add arbitrary Emacs Lisp code (enclosed in backquotes) to `yasnippet` snippets that will be evaluated when they expand. In `sql-mode` and `sql-interactive-mode` there is a variable called `sql-product` that you can check to determine which type of database (`mysql`, `sqlite`, `postgres`, etc.) you are currently working with.

That's basically all you need to know. Here is an example of how to modify your `addcol` snippet:

```
# ...
ALTER TABLE $1 `(if (eq sql-product 'mysql) "ADD" "FROB")` COLUMN \`$2\` $3;
```

This will expand to

```
ALTER TABLE $1 ADD COLUMN \`$2\` $3;
```

for `mysql` and

```
ALTER TABLE $1 FROB COLUMN \`$2\` $3;
```

for other types of databases.